# Android Listview onItemLongClick Listener not working for Second Time

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am implementing LongClick Listener on android list view. Here is the code I am using for that,

```
this.lst_CartDetails.setLongClickable(true);

            this.lst_CartDetails.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    SelectedItem menu = (SelectedItem)cartdetailsAdapter.getItem(arg2);
                    if(menu.getDelete() == 0)
                    {
                        menu.setDelete(1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menu.setDelete(0);
                    }
                    cartdetailsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    //lst_CartDetails.invalidateViews();
                    return true;
                }

            });
```

Long click works for the first time. But if I click(long) again on that item its not responding.

Whats going wrong?

> I found whats going wrong, OnLongClick I am enabling a button within
>   the list item. If that button is not enabled the longclick works
>   normally.

Thanks

Comment: What does setDelete?

Comment: If you're testing on a phone, can you feel the device vibrate to indicate a long press was captured? If you are always able to feel it vibrate, it likely means everything is working, except your code logic might not be. Alternatively, are you printing out a simple `Log` debug to make sure `onItemLongClick` is being called the second time?

Comment: @greenapps setDelete is Just a flag.

Comment: @Brian I am debugging the app and on second time break point is not hit.

Comment: Can you remove or disable your `setLongClickable(true)` line? Because I think that method applies to setting the entire `ListView` as a long clickable. Instead, you want the items inside to be long clickable. I don't know if they're conflicting or anything.

Comment: Can you please rechekc the question, I have edited it @Brian

Comment: @Zach, glad to you know you figured it out.

Comment: @Brian still I dont have a solution, I need to use that button, if button is enabled longpress wont work. How can I overcome it?

Comment: Interesting, could you post some XML or code about how the button is used in the row?

Comment: @Brian fixed that, put my fix as one of the answers

Answer (score 3):

If you are showing/hiding any UI elements which capture focus (eg: Button) then making it visible will take the focus to the item when click/long click happens. To avoid that use

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in the XML layout for the corresponding UI element

Answer (score 0):

For this receive the `ListView` via the `getListVIew()` method and set the `LongItemClickListener` via the `setOnItemLongClickListener()` method.

```
  ListView list = getListView();
    list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1
          int arg2 long arg3) {

        // implement the actions here
        // Return true to consume the click event. In this case the
        // onListItemClick listener is not called anymore.

        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am not extending not a listview but activity. So I guess your suggestion wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the listview cell solved my issue.